# PyCharm Educational Edition could not start on Mac

Tags: java, python, pycharm

I already have PyCharm Community edition on my Mac (Yosemite 10.10.1). Also I wanted to install PyCharm Educational Edition. Community edition works without any problem. But Educational edition couldn't start and I got following error message:

```
    Internal error. Please report to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com


java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryState'
 at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:166)
 at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:46)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
 at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:364)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryState'
 at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:585)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:605)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:236)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:223)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:210)
 at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:124)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:357)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:115)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:86)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:110)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:510)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:492)
 at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:158)
 ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem.getInstance(LocalFileSystem.java:44)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl$1.beforeFileBasedStorageCreate(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:87)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.createFileStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:272)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.createStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:231)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.getStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:122)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initPersistentComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:249)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.access$000(ComponentStoreImpl.java:58)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl$1.run(ComponentStoreImpl.java:82)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:893)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:78)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.initializeComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:186)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:561)
 ... 29 more
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem'
 at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:585)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:605)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:236)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:223)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:210)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:268)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:127)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:116)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:545)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:605)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:236)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:223)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:210)
 at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:167)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ApplicationImpl.java:544)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:198)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:193)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFileManager.getInstance(VirtualFileManager.java:44)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem$LocalFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(LocalFileSystem.java:40)
 ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.UNIXProcess
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher.startupProcess(FileWatcher.java:234)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher.<init>(FileWatcher.java:125)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemImpl.<init>(LocalFileSystemImpl.java:103)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:545)
 ... 66 more
```

Is there any solution?
Thanks,
Ozgur

Answer (score 1):

A friend solved that problem. My computer's language was Turkish. After I changed it from regional settings as English, the problem solved. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. restart your mac OR grep for java and kill all processes related to pycharm
2. extract the executable into a different pycharm directory
3. try executing
4. if failure, run as root

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried both but still same problem. I'm not sure what causes that problem. Community edition works well but that one has a problem.